# Is there an ECMAScript Validator

Tags: javascript, validation

Is there an ECMAScript validator like there is for HTML and CSS?

Ideally, I need some automated way to check against version 3.0 of this standard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). By default it actually validates against a *stricter* subset of ECMAScript 3, but you can toggle some options to make it more tolerant. You can also enable ECMAScript 5 constructs should you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/). Or does it specifically need to be the ecmascript standard?